# How to view a cached Facebook page

Tags: facebook, cached-webpages

I need to save a topic on Facebook. The page contains a very offensive topic, which the author has deleted, when he realized he could be prosecuted.

I tried:

- to save the tab, but I can't save it. When I press <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd>, it tries to save, but immediately cancels.
- "http://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache:" + "url of that facebook topic", but it results in an error message:

> GOOGLE
>   404. Thats an error.
>   The requested URL /search?q="MY FACEBOOK URL CONTAINING THE MENTIONED TOPIC"
>   was not found on this server.
>   That’s all we know.

How can I open a cached version of that page in order to save it for legal purposes?

Comment: Not everything is visible to Google, so not everything will have a cache. If the page has privacy settings or wasn't up for long enough, there may be no cache. Take a screenshot?

Comment: Also, IANAL but something on facebook being 'offensive' probably isn't enough to sue someone unless it's directly libellous, I would think.

Comment: How about a print screen?

Comment: @Alex, print screen isn't enough in legal cases since it could be just an edited image.

Answer (score 2):

The only correct way to retrieve any data from Facebook with respect to law activity is via https://www.facebook.com/safety/groups/law/guidelines/

Cached Google files *should* only work for Facebook pages that are logged out.

So only pages like

- `cache:facebook.com`
- `https://web.archive.org/web/*/facebook.com`

Specifically after that, only public Facebook fan pages can retrieve data. Facebook personal profiles *should* not be showing feed posts logged out.

Answer (score 0):

You can try using an application that can view your cache files:

http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/chrome_cache_view.html